# Can I use an enum as a parameter without including the header that defines it?

Tags: c++, header, enums

One of the functions in my class takes an enum as a parameter:

```
// Foobar.h
class Foobar
{
    void baz(OtherClass::OtherEnum otherEnum);
}
```

Normally in order to get this class to compile, I would have to include the header for `OtherClass`.

```
#include "OtherClass.h"
```

However, `OtherClass` happens to be really big, and I don't want to include it in `Foobar`'s header or it will pollute the compilation unit of everything else that uses `Foobar`.

Is it possible to still pass `OtherEnum` as a parameter without including `OtherClass.h`?

Comment: I don't think so.  VS C++ seems more lenient about this (general) sort of thing re: enums than g++.